# If Column value = string then add row next to column to sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to make an expense chart In Excel.

I have two Columns, one for type of expense and one for cost of expense.

I made a few categories where the types are summed.  The types are Entertainment, Car, Software, Bills, Sports, and Food, so that I can see How much expense is going to each one.

In the column for Type, I made a data validation dropdown, where I can choose which type of expense is being used.

What I'm now trying to do is, for example, at the top under Entertainment:

```
=IF(C:C="Entertainment";SUM(D:D);0)
```

If column C= Entertainment then add Column D To Total Entertainment.

So I want to check the values of column C and if the value of column C = Entertainment then the row next to it should add to Entertainment.

[image]

[Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjtYZ.png)

Comment: Are you using an excel built-in template?

Comment: This layout is all wrong. Make life simple and just use a item and cost column. Sum the costs at the bottom. Make separate tables for each category (laid out side by side with plenty of extra rows at the end) and then have a total at the bottom and a grand total which just sums that final category total row.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=sumif(range for condition, condition, range to sum)`. It should give you the correct response.